# Dragging an image from Chrome to a Qt application

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, google-chrome

I am trying to get the data from an image dragged directly from a browser to my Qt app. I have the following code:

```
void MyView::dropEvent( QDropEvent* event )
{
    QGraphicsView::dropEvent( event );

    if ( event->mimeData()->hasImage() )
    {
        QImage image = qvariant_cast<QImage>( event->mimeData()->imageData() );
        ...
```

This works fine with Firefox (Windows/Mac), Safari (Mac) and IE (Windows). But QMimeData::hasUrl() returns false for Chrome on both Windows and Mac.

On further investigation Qt expects image data in MIME format "application/x-qt-image". It seems that Chrome doesn't provide this. Is there a workaround for Chrome? I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: This is for Qt 5.5.1.

Comment: Well, what mime data *does* Chrome provide? That should be the starting point.